# How to square a density matrix?

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix, linear-algebra

Supposing $x$ is a density matrix. I know purity formula is
$$P = \mathrm{tr}(x^2)$$
But I have doubt about calculating $x^2$.

Is it $x\cdot x$ or $x\cdot x^\dagger$?

Can you give me a reference for your answer?

Comment: Just a remark, not only you can calculate tr(x^2) for x state, it is also possible measure this quantity with the SWAP-test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Squaring matrices works the same way as squaring numbers, i.e. you multiply the matrix by *itself*. Formally, $A^2=A\cdot A$. However, every density matrix $\rho$ is Hermitian, i.e. $\rho=\rho^\dagger$, so $\rho^2 = \rho\cdot\rho = \rho\cdot\rho^\dagger$, anyway.